# Xamarin - The Device.Idiom property is not working in some Android devices

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

The `Device.Idiom` property is used to alter layouts width depending on the device type. But the view is not visible or view width is about 0 while running my app in some device ( *Redmi Note 8 Pro powered by Android 9*).

It's working fine in other devices like emulators, iOS simulators etc. Below is the sample snippet I have used.

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.WidthRequest>
        <OnIdiom
            x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
            Phone="280"
            Tablet="300" />
    </StackLayout.WidthRequest>
</StackLayout>.
```

In the above snippet, I have set the view width as 280 and 300 for Phone and Tablet respectively.

> I think, I got this freaky error after the update of Xamarin.Froms to
>   4.6.0.772.

**Working Environment**

- Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
- Xamarin.Mac Version: 6.18.2.1
- Xamarin.iOS Version: 13.18.2.1
- Xamarin.Android Version: 10.3.1.4

**Test Device Details**

- Device Model: Redmi Note 8 Pro
- MIUI Version: MIUI 11.0.4
- Android Version: Android 9 Pie

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: We do not have Redmi Note 8 Pro to test. Do you test on other device or same version of Android emulator, does it work well?

Comment: @MSFT yes, It's woking fine

Comment: Hi! I'm facing the same issue. Have you tried to add the "Default" tag and set it to a value? Does it work then?